# Creating ASP.NET MVC users using ApplicationUserManager throws DbContext has been disposed error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Part of my application requires the importing of users at a large scale, this information is supplied via an excel document which is uploaded via a View.

Due to the size of this batch and several other processes which need to be kicked off for each user, including welcome emails that take quite a long time to complete I have opted to use threads to do this to avoid any long loading screens to the user.

In order to use threads I have needed to make several variables accessible to the threaded function, including `ApplicationUserManager`, `HttpRequestBase` and `UrlHelper` which all get populated in the `ActionResult` function that starts this `Thread`

This is the controller function that populates this information:

```
public ActionResult importExternalUsers()
{
        BulkUserImportProcessHelperModel helperModel = new BulkUserImportProcessHelperModel();
        helperModel.userManager = this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); ;
        helperModel.urlContext = this.Url;
        helperModel.httprequestBase = this.Request;
        helperModel.filePath = @"C:\Users\tiaan\Desktop\MultipleUserCreation.xlsx";

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(bulkUserImportProcess));
        thread.Start(helperModel);
        return View();
}
```

As you can see the models get populated then a thread is created. I made use of a "Helper model" in that case just to pass the parameters to the function I started in a `Thread` as I could not find an easy way, if any at all, to pass multiple parameters to a function designed for threaded use.

This is the threaded function which imports the Excel document and starts the loop that registers the users:

```
public static void bulkUserImport(object objectParams)
{
        BulkUserImportProcessHelperModel helperModel = (BulkUserImportProcessHelperModel)objectParams;

        List<MedicalProfessionalRegistration> usersToReg = IO.InputOutput.ImportExcelDocument(helperModel.filePath);

        foreach (var user in usersToReg)
        {
            AccountController.registerUser(user, helperModel.userManager, helperModel.urlContext, helperModel.httprequestBase);
        }
}
```

So far, although probably a little unconventional, all is working. Adding a breakpoint in this function after the creation of the `helperModel` variable reveals that all the fields were populated as expected.

My problems start at the static `AccountController` function responsible for the creation of the users.

```
public static bool registerUser(MedicalProfessionalRegistration model, ApplicationUserManager userManager, UrlHelper urlHelper, HttpRequestBase request)
{
        string password = membershipPasswordGenerator(10, 10, 5, 1);

        model.Password = password;
        model.ConfirmPassword = password;

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };

        var result = userManager.Create(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            IO.Identities.registerUser(user.Id, IO.IdentityRank.User);
            IO.Identities.storeUserIdentityMeta(user.Id, model);

            string code = userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
            string callbackUrl = urlHelper.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code, rst = "T" }, protocol: request.Url.Scheme);

            IO.Email.confirmEmailAccountRegister(user.Email, callbackUrl);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Currently, I am getting an exception on

```
var result = userManager.Create(user, model.Password);
```

that reads:

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.Connection.get()

What's weird to me is that sometimes it actually populates the database with a single user from this list then seems to fail on the next iteration of the loop in `bulkUserImport`. While other times it fails on the first one almost immediately.

I believe it has something to do with UserManager being disposed as the stack trace says, as well as the userManager being `null`

This thread could run upwards of an hour (and the IIS server has been configured appropriately for this)

So ultimately what I think this comes down to, is there any way that I can prevent these fields from being disposed, or is there something else that's wrong with my logic here that I have become oblivious to after spending the last day tinkering with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your main mistake is using the thread here. Because you don't wait until it ends but in the same time you pass the owin context to it, it starts and runs. But your main thread that created the context ends and disposes the db context. Do not spawn new thread internally to handle long running operation!

Comment: @WiktorZychla So is there a way to use a thread for my purposes here? If not what would alternative would you suggest?

Comment: @WiktorZychla is correct, and you can make use of the Task Parallel Library to set up what you need to do. If you use async tasks and await the results inside the method that uses the DB context, the runtime will handle threading for you and keep your hands off of it, and push tasks to a background thread pool as needed automatically. As long as you are waiting for results the DB context won't go out of scope. [Start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) if you aren't familiar with TPL.

Comment: I should also mention that whatever method does all this work should be a Task itself, and await it from the caller (ImportExternalUsers method?) so that the server can still support other requests while all this is running. I would suspect that quite a bit of the time involved is IO related, so using TPL will make your code non-blocking and while the threads are sitting there waiting for IO, the server can also be doing something else.

Comment: To be honest, you architecture is a mess:) You should at least use old fashioned 3 layer architecture (Presentation, Business Layer, Data access layer) Right now controller is calling some helper which calls controller?:)

I strongly encourage you also to read about the concept of IoC (Inversion of control) and DI (Dependency Injection) - Autofac for example. Then you can define your data context as injection into some repository and you can define its lifetime. I also advice to use Task.Run which utilize tasks from pool instead of creating new tasks "by hand"